# MySQL export/import yields error

Tags: mysql

When trying to export and import an 58G database yields the following error:

> ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000
>   bytes

Dump created using `mysqldump -q --opt` and import is just `cat bigfile.sql|mysql ...`

MySQL versions:

- Import: 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1
- Export: 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10-log (Ubuntu)

Comment: Are you changing from MyISAM to InnoDB or vice versa? Or the collation? If so, check the limits on any char constraints on the schema (like `varchar(X)`, they are calculated differently

Comment: @DrColossos: Isn't the engine type defined in the dump file? Nothing has been changed in the import/export.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a character set conversion issue to me, the clue being *bytes* rather than *characters*. Are you going from ASCII to a multibyte charset, e.g. Unicode? Check the target database, check your environment (`NLS_` env vars), check the dumpfile itself (e.g. if you were using UTF8 in the source that's Unicode but not multibyte if you only used the lower code page).

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track! I actually tried to import the SQL-dump into a remote system (not local) and it worked. I will try to change the env and see if it works.